# Бесконечное извлечение из двух set- ов

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Есть 2 pojo класса:

```
public class Component {
    private String ID;
    private Set<Environment> environmentSet;

public class Environment {
    private String host;
    private String name;
    private Set<Component> components;
```

И контейнер для второго:

```
public class EnvironmentContainer {
    private List<Environment> allEnvironments;
```

Мне по данному пути нужно вернуть лист из контейнера

```
@RequestMapping("/environments")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Environment> getAllEnvironments() {
        return environmentcontainer.getAllEnvironments();
    }
```

При выполнении возникает ошибка, скорее всего из за взаимосвязи между pojo, построенной на set:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the
>   response has been committed   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:466)

Слышал в спринге есть аннотация, которая обрубает бесконечное извлечение, или есть другие пути как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Нижеизложенное справедливо если вы используете Jackson для сериализации ваших бинов.*

В Jackson есть аннотации, позволяющие управлять сериализацией бинов, связанных циклическими ссылками. Это [`@JsonManagedReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) и [`@JsonBackReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html). Первой помечается поле или геттер основного класса (с которого начинается сериализация) со ссылками на зависимые объекты, второй - поле или геттер зависимого класса со ссылкой на основной:

```
public class Environment {
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Component> components;
}

public class Component {
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Environment> environmentSet;
}
```

Теперь Jackson не уйдёт в бесконечную рекурсию при сериализации.

Другая аннотация, которая может помочь - [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html). Поля, помеченные такой аннотацией, не включаются в сериализованный объект. Если объекты класса `Component` никогда не будут  сериализовываться отдельно от объектов `Environment`, то можно пометить поле `environmentSet` аннотацией `@JsonIgnore`, эффект будет аналогичный.

Ещё один вариант - [`@JsonIdentityInfo`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html). Этой аннотацией помечается весь класс. С её помощью можно подсказать Jackson'у, как определить уникальный ключ объекта (например, по полю `ID`):

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
    property = "ID")
public class Environment { ... }
```

Встретив при сериализации объект с ключом, который он уже обрабатывал, Jackson подставит вместо него его ключ.

Также есть возможность управлять сериализацией циклических ссылок через [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) (подробнее об этом и других способах читайте в [этой статье](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)), но это требует регистрации в Spring'е кастомного сериализатора.

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)