# Как исправить бесконечную загрузку коллекций энтити?

Tags: java, spring, lazyloading

У меня есть энтити `Car` и в ней сет `Holder`.

```
@Entity
public class Car {

  // fields

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "holder_car", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "holder_id"))
  @NotNull
  private Set<Holder> holder;
```

Также вот энтити `Holder`.

```
@Entity
public class Holder {

  // fields

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "holder")
  private Set<Car> cars;
```

Когда пытаюсь вытащить энтити `Holder` через GET-метод, то ответ входит в "бесконечный цикл". То есть, ответ присылает все поля и когда доходит до поля `cars` начинает выдавать поля этой энтити, потом доходит до поля `holder` и выдает его поля. И так до бесконечности.
Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Читал что вроде как может помочь Lazy-загрузка, но почему-то ответ приходит тот же. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Для чего вы используете связь многие ко многим?

Comment: @GenCloud Ну логичней будет сделать связь один владелец-несколько машин, но это не меняет ситуацию, как я понимаю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Бесконечное извлечение из двух set- ов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573766/%d0%91%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-set-%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Так берите и делайте один ко многим, а чтобы избежать рекурсии в результате запроса уберите маппинг из Car и пропишите маппинг в Holder так @OneToMany(cascade = ALL) private Set<Car> cars; и не используйте джойны, интерпретатор сущностей сам поймет куда ему нужно бцдет вставить ключи (сгенерирует доп таблийу в базе для связи)

Comment: @GenCloud Сделал так как вы сказали, но при получении Holder массив Car пустой, при том что в базе они есть и у них указан holder_id

Comment: Пересоберите базу и заного сделайте вставку данных

Comment: @GenCloud Создал новую базу, в ней то же самое. Вроде бы сделал все как вы написали, но не знаю..

Comment: Покажите код,при котором возникает проблема

Comment: @VladMamaev Вроде уже исправил ситуацию с аннотацией JsonIdentityInfo.

Comment: Возвращайте из контроллера не Entity, а DTO с нужными полями

Comment: @Nick Да, так и сделал, только ответ пришел поздно)